# I'm not sadistic or masochistic, but I love to play

Tags: riddle

I can be the life of a party,
or just for you all alone.

I may be 2 faced,
but when you use me I'll show you only one.

Anyone can own me,
but most must pay a price.

Damage me and I'll sing & skip,
but if you break me that's when I'll stop playing!

**What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could be a:

> **VINYL RECORD**

*I can be the life of a party,*
*or just for you all alone.*

> You can play a record to listen to music by yourself in your room, or use it as the soundtrack to your social occasions.

*I may be 2 faced,*
*but when you use me I'll show you only one.*

> A record has two grooved sides (*faces*), but only one is in contact with the stylus of a record player while it plays.

*Anyone can own me,*
*but most must pay a price.*

> Anyone can own a vinyl record. In most cases this will be by buying it from a shop or seller (*paying a price*).

*Damage me and I'll sing & skip,*
*but if you break me that's when I'll stop playing!*

> If you scratch a record (*damage* it) the stylus will *skip* or get stuck, interrupting its 'singing'. Break it in two and you won't be able to play it at all!

Comment: You 'nailed' it. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Are you a

> **Guitar ?**

I can be the life of a party,
or just for you all alone.

> You could play the guitar in a party on stage, or all alone

I may be 2 faced,
but when you use me I'll show you only one.

> Guitar has two faces, and only one faces people when being played.

Anyone can own me,
but most must pay a price.

> Anyone can own a guitar, but some have to buy it.

Damage me and I'll sing & skip,
but if you break me that's when I'll stop playing!

> Once the guitar strings break, the guitar would not produce anymore
>  sound.

Comment: No. But good guess.

It breaks down on this:

"Damage me and I'll sing & skip, but if you break me that's when I'll stop playing!"